# Minimum common remainder of division

Tags: algorithm, numbers

I have *n* pairs of numbers: ( p[1], s[1] ), ( p[2], s[2] ), ... , ( p[n], s[n] )

Where p[i] is integer greater than 1; s[i] is integer : 0 <= s[i] < p[i]

Is there any way to determine minimum positive integer *a* , such that for each pair :

```
( s[i] + a ) mod p[i] != 0
```

Anything better than brute force ?

Comment: Shouldn't it be 0 <= s[i] < p[i] because s[i] = p[i] is equivalent to s[i] = 0?

Comment: As a reminder, PPCG (Programming Puzzles & Code Golf) is not the easier site of SO (unlike Math.SE and MO), it hosts programming contests. There had been proposals to rename the site to Programming Contests & Code Golf, but SE doesn't care about PPCG...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to do better than brute force. Brute force would be **O**(A·n), where A is the minimum valid value for *a* that we are looking for.

The approach described below uses a [min-heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap) and achieves **O**(n·log(n) + A·log(n)) time complexity.

First, notice that replacing *a* with a value of the form (p[i] - s[i]) + *k* * p[i] leads to a reminder equal to zero in the i<sup>th</sup> pair, for any positive integer *k*. Thus, the numbers of that form are invalid *a* values (the solution that we are looking for is different from all of them).

The proposed algorithm is an efficient way to generate the numbers of that form (for all *i* and *k*), *i.e.* the invalid values for *a*, **in increasing order**. As soon as the current value differs from the previous one by more than 1, it means that there was a valid *a* in-between.

The pseudocode below details this approach.

```
1. construct a min-heap from all the following pairs (p[i] - s[i], p[i]), 
    where the heap comparator is based on the first element of the pairs.
2. a0 = -1; maxA = lcm(p[i])
3. Repeat
     3a. Retrieve and remove the root of the heap, (a, p[i]).
     3b. If a - a0 > 1 then the result is a0 + 1. Exit.
     3c. if a is at least maxA, then no solution exists. Exit.
     3d. Insert into the heap the value (a + p[i], p[i]).
     3e. a0 = a
```

*Remark*: it is possible for such an *a* to not exist. If a valid *a* is not found below LCM(p[1], p[2], ... p[n]), then it is guaranteed that no valid *a* exists.

---

I'll show below an **example** of how this algorithm works.

Consider the following (p, s) pairs: { (2, 1), (5, 3) }.

The first pair indicates that *a* should avoid values like *1, 3, 5, 7, ...*, whereas the second pair indicates that we should avoid values like *2, 7, 12, 17, ...* .

The min-heap initially contains the first element of each sequence (step 1 of the pseudocode) -- shown in bold below:

- **1**, 3, 5, 7, ...
- **2**, 7, 12, 17, ...

We retrieve and remove the head of the heap, *i.e.*, the minimum value among the two bold ones, and this is **1**. We add into the heap the next element from that sequence, thus the heap now contains the elements 2 and 3:

- 1, **3**, 5, 7, ...
- **2**, 7, 12, 17, ...

We again retrieve the head of the heap, this time it contains the value **2**, and add the next element of that sequence into the heap:

- 1, **3**, 5, 7, ...
- 2, **7**, 12, 17, ...

The algorithm continues, we will next retrieve value **3**, and add 5 into the heap:

- 1, 3, **5**, 7, ...
- 2, **7**, 12, 17, ...

Finally, now we retrieve value **5**. At this point we realize that the value **4** is not among the invalid values for *a*, thus that is the solution that we are looking for.

Comment: What about `a0` ? Looks like it constant and never changes. Is it necessary ?

Comment: Must be some additional `a0` assigment probably

Comment: indeed, i missed an assignment. `a0` is the largest value currently known to not be valid.

Comment: Bthw, what means "values of the form (p[i] - s[i]) + k * p[i] lead to a reminder equal to zero" ? Reminder of devision by what ? `( (p[i] - s[i]) + k * p[i] ) mod p[i] == p[i] - s[i]`, not zero (if s[i] != p[i])

Comment: @obratim it's in the sense that if we replace _a_ with that value, we have a reminder equal to 0.

Comment: @obratim The idea is that those are the invalid _a_ values, the ones that must be skipped. For a specific (p[i], s[i]) pair in the input, the first invalid value for _a_ is p[i] - s[i], and every time we add p[i] to it we get another invalid _a_. The heap provides an efficient way to retrieve the next (smallest) invalid _a_ considering all the (p[i], s[i]) pairs.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163214/discussion-between-obratim-and-qwertyman).

Answer (score 2):

I can think of two different solutions. First:

```
p_max = lcm (p[0],p[1],...,p[n]) - 1;
for a = 0 to p_max:
    zero_found = false;
    for i = 0 to n:
        if ( s[i] + a ) mod p[i] == 0:
            zero_found = true;
            break;
    if !zero_found:
        return a;
return -1;
```

I suppose this is the one you call "brute force". Notice that `p_max` represents Least Common Multiple of `p[i]`s - 1 (solution is either in the closed interval `[0, p_max]`, or it does not exist). Complexity of this solution is `O(n * p_max)` in the worst case (plus the running time for calculating lcm!). There is a better solution regarding the time complexity, but it uses an additional binary array - classical time-space tradeoff. Its idea is similar to the Sieve of Eratosthenes, but for remainders instead of primes :)

```
p_max = lcm (p[0],p[1],...,p[n]) - 1;
int remainders[p_max + 1] = {0};
for i = 0 to n:
    int rem = s[i] - p[i];
    while rem >= -p_max:
        remainders[-rem] = 1;
        rem -= p[i];
for i = 0 to n:
    if !remainders[i]:
         return i;
return -1;
```

Explanation of the algorithm: first, we create an array `remainders` that will indicate whether certain negative remainder exists in the whole set. What is a negative remainder? It's simple, notice that 6 = 2 mod 4 is equivalent to 6 = -2 mod 4. If `remainders[i] == 1`, it means that if we add `i` to one of the `s[j]`, we will get `p[j]` (which is 0, and that is what we want to avoid).  Array is populated with all possible negative remainders, up to `-p_max`. Now all we have to do is search for the first `i`, such that `remainder[i] == 0` and return it, if it exists - notice that the solution does not have to exists. In the problem text, you have indicated that you are searching for the minimum *positive* integer, I don't see why zero would not fit (if all `s[i]` are positive). However, if that is a strong requirement, just change the `for` loop to start from 1 instead of 0, and increment `p_max`.
The complexity of this algorithm is `n + sum (p_max / p[i]) = n + p_max * sum (1 / p[i])`, where `i` goes from to `0` to `n`. Since all `p[i]`s are at least 2, that is asymptotically better than the brute force solution.

An example for better understanding: suppose that the input is (5,4), (5,1), (2,0). `p_max` is `lcm(5,5,2) - 1 = 10 - 1 = 9`, so we create array with 10 elements, initially filled with zeros. Now let's proceed pair by pair:

- from the first pair, we have `remainders[1] = 1` and `remainders[6] = 1`
- second pair gives `remainders[4] = 1` and `remainders[9] = 1`
- last pair gives `remainders[0] = 1`, `remainders[2] = 1`, `remainders[4] = 1`, `remainders[6] = 1` and `remainders[8] = 1`.

Therefore, first index with zero value in the array is 3, which is a desired solution.

Comment: note that it is not necessary for the minimum value for _a_ to be below max(p) -- consider the following example: (p, s) = { (2, 1), (5, 1), (5, 3) } -- the minimum valid _a_ is 6 in this case.

Comment: @qwertyman In this case my algorithm would output 0 as a solution, I have commented that special case (0 is always considered a regular remainder in any system modulo `n`, so I don't see why `a` should be > 0) . If `a` cannot be nenegative, but positive, then you are right - we should extend the loop over max(p). Is there an example where some of `s[i]` is zero and we still need to go over max(p)?

Comment: yes, for example if the set of (p, s) pairs is { (2, 1), (3, 0), (5, 1), (5, 3) }, then the values from 0 to 7 do not work, _a_ = 8 is the minimum valid one.

Comment: @qwertyman Excellent example! Actually, `p_max` should be lcm(p[i]) - 1, that is the highest possible value (or the solution does not exist), edited my answer. I have now checked your solution, it is really elegant - upvoted! Notice that the stop condition for generating new number on the heap is also when you reach lcm(p[i]), so unfortunately calculating lcm cannot be avoided either way.

Comment: thank you for the appreciation and for taking my suggestion into account -
 upvoted, too! Indeed, the lcm is necessary in both solutions.